# Not able to access object sub class's variable? (Java / Android)

Tags: java, android, variables, object, subclass

I've got a custom class called 'Quad' which creates a textured quad to use as a sprite in my 2D OpenGL ES 2.0 game.

```
public class Quad(){

//Quad creation stuff here

}
```

Then I have a separate subclass (i.e. in a different file - not an innerclass)

```
public class hero extends Quad(){

//Variables relating specifically to this character
int heroX = 0;
int heroY = 0;

}
```

I create my object like so:

```
Quad hero = new Hero();
```

However, if I attempt to access the 'heroX' and 'heroY' variables, I get nothing.....

So I'll try

```
hero.heroX
```

but the above doesn't pick this variable up.

It will. however, find variables that are located in my Quad class.  But I would have thought that by extending my Quad class into my Hero class, they would be available through my object.

Could someone please explain where my thinking is going wrong and how I can access these 2 variables? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `hero` is of type `Quad`, not type `Hero`, hence the compiler only knows that it is a `Quad`. Use the specific subtype if you want access to `Hero` methods.

Comment: If he his using accessors.. I don't think that's the problem. In other languages, maybe. If not, my answer is atrociously wrong.

Comment: @LewsTherin - the correct answer is that both access and the correct type is required. Java, however, is package private by default (so any classes in the same package can read those variables), not private.

Comment: Yes @ianhanniballake, I've just declared it as Hero, so now I'm saying Hero hero = new Hero(); and it is working OK - doing this I can access all methods and variables from both Quad class and Hero class - why is this?  Surely if I declare hero as a Quad() which it is and then when I'm creating the object, create it as a new 'Hero' (which is also a Quad) - surely the compiler knows it's a Hero as well as a Quad? If not, what would ever be the point of saying 'Quad hero = new Hero() - the like of which I've seen many times in Java code......confused!! :-/

Comment: @Zippy - let's say you have a `Hero` and a `Commoner`, both who are subclasses of `Quad` and you want a list of everyone. You could then make a list of `Quad`s and put both `Hero`s and `Commoner`s in that List and access all of the common `Quad` variables and methods without having to know who is who. That is polymorphism (not needing to know what subclass they are to be able to access the shared behavior).

Comment: @ianhanniballake If Quad provides accessors that can be overridden, type is not an issue. Liking the new show?

Comment: I've actually asked another question specific to understanding polymorhism over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267851/polymorphism-in-java-and-creating-objects-from-these-classes would be grateful if you could explain in a bit more details over there -thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The only thing I still don't get is that I could say Hero hero = new Hero() and Commoner commoner = new Commoner() - and I would still be able to access Quad's methods and variables, so I still don't get the purpose of something like Quad hero = new Hero() :-(