# Polymorphism in Java and creating objects from these classes

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

I'm a little confused exactly about how polymorphism and extending classes etc... works in Java when creating objects from these classes.

I recently had a problem which someone on here helped me resolved (see [Not able to access object sub class's variable? (Java / Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267433/not-able-to-access-object-sub-classs-variable-java-android)) for background.

I was attempting to create an object like so:

```
Quad hero = new Hero();
```

Where Hero was a subclass of Quad();

I had variables in my Hero class which I wasn't above to access.

The solution was to change my object creation to:

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
```

doing this, through my hero object, I was able to access all methods and variables in both my Quad and Hero classes.

My question now is - Why is this?

And with this in mind, when would it be useful to use my original method:

```
Quad hero = new Hero();
```

That one makes sense to me as Hero is also a quad.  I've seen this type of declaration many times in Java code examples, and thought I understood, it but recent events have proved otherwise.

Would be grateful if someone could explain this for me - thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assume `OtherHero` is also a subclass from `Quad` with different behaviour:

This will work fine:

```
Quad hero = new Hero();
// some code
hero = new OtherHero();
```

Whereas the following won't compile:

```
Hero hero = new Hero();
// some code
hero = new OtherHero();
```

This doesn't seem to be useful. Now assume you have a method, that has `Quad` as return type. I'll write it in pseudocode:

```
Quad method() {
    if (condition)
        return new Hero();
    else
        return new OtherHero();
}
```

So you actually don't know if it will return a `Hero` or an `OtherHero`

Now, you can write:

```
Quad foo = method();
```

Now, you actually don't know the exact type of `foo`, but you can use it as `Quad`.

A popular example is `java.util.List`

You can write:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

`List` is an interface, implemented by `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and many other classes. Without knowing the code, we don't know which class exactly is returned by `Arrays.asList()`, but we can use it as a `List`.

Comment: Hmmmm... interesting @jlordo, thanks.  So if I had for example, enemy1, enemy2, enemy3 and hero, all created as quads, and wanted to group them into array, then I would be able to as they are all Quads?  But then how would I access variables that are stored only in the subclasses? (say for example Hero sub class has a variable stored in it, that the Enemy class doesn't.  How would I access those variables as they are not in the base class? I can't get to them via the object, without changing it's type to Hero, but then I can't group it with the Enemies?  Thanks!!

Comment: @Zippy: This depends on how you want to access those variables, and what you want to do with them. You can safely cast, if you check with the `instanceof` operator first. I'd prefer to make a `Quad` interface (or abstract class) and only use it's methods. The variables should be encapsulated anyway, so you can access them via the methods in the classes.

Comment: Thanks @jlordo - could I ask you to edit you answer to give an example of you above comment?  (on how to access the variables as I have described in my comments? I generally find it easier to understand through way of examples) - then I will read and mark your answer - thank again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the variable type as `Quad`, means that the variable also can reference other types of subclasses of `Quad`, not only `Hero`. And if you pass that reference around, the receiver would only know that it is "some kind of quad", and can't rely on it being a `Hero`. Hence, it can not access the fields of the reference that are declared only in the subclass.

As for when to use that kind of assignment, I usually only do it when working with interface types. Like:

```
public List<SomeObject> doSomething() {
    List<SomeObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // do something
    return result;
}
```

But it's really just a habit.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your object in a variable of `Quad` then, for all the compiler knows, the object stored in that variable is a `Quad` and nothing more. It may be of a subtype, sure, but the compiler has no idea what that subtype is. For all it knows, that subtype will be introducing absolutely zero members to the base type. If the compiler has no guarantee that the object is anything more than a `Quad`, then it doesn't want to allow you to do anything more than what it would allow you to do with a `Quad`.

Granted, *you* can see that this variable is only ever assigned a `new Hero()` expression. And, granted, you may know that a specific variable will only hold objects of the `Hero` type. But this is runtime information that you can deduce in practice. The compiler can't bother to calculate all these scenarios. That's why it has you. If you *know* that objects stored in that variable will always be of type `Hero`, you can go on and express it to the compiler.

One reason the language allows you to cast an object to a super type is because in many occasions you want to pass that object to a method that doesn't have to know about all the possible subtypes of the base class (say, `Hero`) but only that the passed object is at least of a base class (say, `Quad`). Another typical scenario is when you want to store various objects that are not all of the same specific type (they are not all `Hero`), but they all have a common ancestor (they are all `Quad`) and you want to do something with them, collectively. In general, then, casting objects to an ancestor class is permitted because **it is useful to make objects compatible with their base type in situations where that base type is required**.